# dynamic image generation with .htaccess

Tags: image, .htaccess, dynamic

I need to use dynamic image generation through .htaccess in case the requested image doesn't exist but one thing is not clear to me..... if I use the following code in .htaccess:

```
# Images 
RewriteCond     %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}      !-f
RewriteCond     %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}      !-d
RewriteRule     ^static/images/([-\w]+)/([0-9]+)/([\.-\w]+)$   image_handler.php?area=$1& id=$2&filename=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
```

the image gets generated only when the url to that image is requested from the address bar(hope that makes sense) and I thought it should work if the image is called in the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

From the point of view of the web server, there is no difference between answering a request that was made by inputting the URL directly on a browser's address bar or one that was the result of a browser seeing a resource getting referenced by an `<img>` tag and performing the request to fetch it. (The only difference here is that one will have an HTTP referer header set and the other will not, but that's irrelevant to your case)

Both of these cases will result in what you want, which is having the request rewritten by the webserver and passed onto the PHP script handler that will (hopefully) return your image. So your assumption is correct.

What will not work is attempting to access those "virtual images" through other means, like server-side scripting, for example. What you are performing with those rules is to make your web server interpret requests coming via HTTP and towards `static/images/` as something that should be served by a program that you've specified. It will then fulfill the request with the output of said program (in this case `image_handler.php`). Those images are never stored or copied on the server's disk or anything like that (unless you make the script do so, of course). So on the server side, attempting to find those images anywhere on disk will not work, the supposed corresponding directory structure may not even exist.

On the client side (via HTML, Javascript), they should behave just like you were dealing with static resources (cache considerations aside, as we don't know how your script deals in that aspect).